# Is there a way to say an IList<xxx> is both a specific class and an interface

Tags: c#, ilist

I would like to declare a property as:

```
IList<BaseNode and IComplexType> ComplexTypes { get; }
```

All elements in the list inherit from BaseNode and implement IComplexType. Is there any way to do this? It won't work to create a class BaseNodeComplexType because the nodes in the list are all sub-classes of BaseNode.

**Update:** I didn't think this through to explain fully. I have sub classes such as XmlNode. XmlNode inherits from BaseNode. I also have XmlComplexNode that inherits from XmlNode and implements IComplexType. But XmlNode does not inherit from IComplexType (and I don't want it to as I use "obj is IComplexType" in places. apologies for not adding this originally.

Comment: Is there a reason that the nodes in the list have to be subclasses of BaseNode, and not a custom type which is both a `BaseNode` and a `IComplexType`?

Comment: @MattBall I'd assume that each subclass implements `IComplexType` differently, though on further reflection I suppose an intermediate base could implement all the interface members as virtual, and throw `NotImplementedExceptions`...

Comment: @EsotericScreenName They can each implement IComplexType however they want if the base class which "implements" IComplexType does so using abstract methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but you could solve it with generics?

```
class CustomObj<T> where T : BaseNode, IComplexType
{
   IList<T> ComplexTypes { get; }
}
```

For more details about the used generic-constraints, see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.100%29).

Comment: +1 This is pretty much what the OP is asking for "*only allow types which derive from `BaseNode` and implement `IComplexType`*".

Comment: Yes James, but how are you going to create an instance of `CustomObj`, what are you going to use as type? I'm not sure if this is this the full-solution...

Comment: Thank you - perfect. (I'm still not using generics regularly - I need to think of them at times like this.)

Comment: @Kolky I may have misunderstood the original question, however, I thought the OP has multiple derivations of `BaseNode` which implement `IComplexType` therefore my thinking would be `T` in this scenario could be `BaseType`.

Answer (score 6):

The correct behaviour would be to derive a new class i.e. `ComplexBaseNode` which has both the inherited features of BaseNode and interface IComplexType, would it not?

Comment: This. Create an abstract `ComplexBaseNode` which inherits from BaseNode and implements IComplexType with abstract methods. Then, implementations of ComplexBaseNode are guaranteed to be both of the things you need. Provided that you control all implementations of BaseNode it would be trivial to make them derive from ComplexBaseNode instead.

Comment: I added an update I should have included in the original question. Otherwise this is a very good solution. Thank you.

Comment: Ah I gotcha, I take it Kolky's solution worked correctly then?

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct way to do that.

But you can use generics to achieve that: what about a generic type parameter?

```
public class YourClass<T> 
  where T : BaseNode, IComplexType
```

... and your property will look like this:

```
IList<T> ComplexTypes { get; }
```

Comment: One major limitation with that approach is that it requires that all the objects that will ever be placed in the list derive from a single known base type which satisfies both constraints.  Unfortunately, not only is there no general way of finding a suitable base type--there's no guarantee that such a type will even exist.

Comment: @supercat It'll depend on particular case. In what are you based to say *there is no general way of finding a suitable base type [...]*?

Comment: The main situation in which it would be useful to specify both a base-type constraint and an interface constraint is when there exist two more more types (e.g. `P` and `Q`) such that `P` and `Q` both derive from `BaseNode`, and they both implement `IComplexType`, but `P` does not inherit from `Q` nor from any of `Q`'s ancestors other than `BaseNode`, and likewise `Q` does not inherit from `P` nor its ancestors.  While both `P` and `Q` satisfy the constraints above, there is no possible type `T` satisfying both constraints such that objects of both types `P` and `Q` could go into a `List<T>`.

Comment: There are a few ways one can get around this.  One which works pretty well is to define an interface `ISelf<out T>` with a read-only `Self` property of type `T`, and for each interface one wants to combine with other constraints (e.g. `IComplexType`), define an interface `IComplexTypeAndSelf<out T>` which inherits both `IComplexType` and `ISelf<T>`.  If each type which implements `IComplexType` also implements `IComplexTypeAndSelf<[itsowntype]>`, then every such object which inherits from `BaseNode` could be cast to `IComplexTypeAndSelf<BaseNode>`, and thus be stored in a...

Comment: ...`IList<IComplexTypeAndSelf<BaseNode>>`.  Any number of constraints may be combined in this fashion, and typecasts may be done in any order.  The two biggest problems with this approach are: (1) An object of the aforementioned type can't be used as a `BaseNode` without either typecasting or using its `Self` property; (2) if every object which implements `ISelf<T>.Self` returns a reference to itself, then an `IFooAndSelf<IBarAndSelf<BaseType>>` may be safely cast to an `IBarAndSelf<IFooAndSelf<BaseType>>`, or to a `BaseType`, or an `IBar`, etc. but nothing would prevent...

Comment: ...a "rogue implementation" of `IFooAndSelf<BaseType>.Self` returning something which inherited `BaseType` but didn't implement `IFoo`, while the implementation itself implemented `IFoo` but didn't inherit from `BaseType`.  If `.net` included a special interface equivalent to `ISelf<T>` and had made all classes implicitly implement it so object would return referneces to themselves, such danger could be avoided, but no such feature exists.

Comment: @supercat I understand you. BTW don't you feel that you're covering some complex scenario? Or what's most important: check OP text. It says "BaseNode and IComplexType". Pay attention to the "AND". OP don't care about your use case, because OP wants types that both inherit `BaseNode` and implement `IComplexType`. There's no need to support the use case of "adding BaseNode that don't implement IComplexType" or "an IComplexType not deriving BaseNode" (continues in the next comment)

Comment: @supercat But after all, why are you saying that setence **there no general way of finding a suitable base type--there's no guarantee that such a type will even exist**? You've no guarantee that such type will even **be implemented** but you've 100% guarantee that such `List<T>` won't store any object that doesn't derive `BaseNode` and implements `IComplexType`.

Comment: @supercat I've double-checked your comments again and I find that maybe you're misunderstanding generic constraints. `where T : BaseNode, IComplexType` has effect in the first descendant and any other descendand of a descendant of `BaseNode`. I mean that if `A : BaseNode `, then `B : A` and `C : B`, the so-called generic constraint will work either if any of the descendants or the `BaseNode` itself has implemented `IComplexType`.

Comment: If types `P` and `Q` exist as I have described, then one could create a `YourClass<P>` and store instances of `P` into it; one could likewise create a `YourClass<Q>` and store instances of `Q` into it. One could not, however, store instances of `Q` into a `YourClass<P>`, nor could one store instances of `P` into a `YourClass<Q>`. Instances of both `P` and `Q` could go in a `List<BaseNode>`, but one cannot create a `YourClass<BaseNode>` if `BaseNode` doesn't implement `IComplexType`. If it's possible to create a `YourClass<T>` which can hold instances of `P` and `Q`, what would `T` be?

Comment: @supercat Now understand your concerns. But are you sure `BaseNode` would ever exist as an instance? And, of course, why you feel that `List<T> where T : BaseNode, IComplexType` would be dangerous because you can store **any** instance that inherits `BaseNode` and implements `IComplexType`? What would be `T`? Whatever, but restricted to the generic constraint. If you store a extremly derived class of `BaseNode`, what's the problem? You implemented such property `List<T>` in order to have typed access to what an implementation of `IComplexType` and a derived class of `BaseNode` would expose.

Comment: Trying to have a field of type `List<T> where T:BaseNode,IComplexType` isn't "dangerous"--it won't compile; to define a field as being a `List<T>`, the type *containing* the field has to have a single generic type `T`, and all items in the list must not only satisfy the original constraints but must *also* derive from `T`.  If everything one would want to put in the list inherited from a common type `TCommon` that met all the constraints, one could just constrain things to `TCommon`.  Otherwise, no matter how one defines `T`, one will be unable to store all the things one would want to.

Comment: @supercat Sorry? What have you tried so far??? It won't compile? Are we talking about .NET and C# or what?

Answer (score 0):

Where's your `IList<>` residing. If you use a generic parameter `xxx` (from your title), you can say `where xxx : BaseNode, IComplexType`.

Also consider if `BaseNode` could already implement `IComplexType`, possibly abstractly.

Answer (score -1):

The definition of  `IList<T>` means that you can only specify one type for the elements in the list.

Create a container class: `ComplexNodeContainer<T,U>`, that will contain BaseNode objects implementing also IComplexType, when T=BaseNode and U=IComplexType.

When you set the "contained" object(in the constructor preferably, or via a method/property), you can check whether it implements both types or not, and act accordingly.

You can have two properties to retrieve it, one as type `T` (or `BaseNode`), one as type `U` (or `IComplexType` in this case).

Then you can define your property as: `IList<ComplexNodeContainer>`